# AJAX not firing in Safari or Safari mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, safari

For some reason, my AJAX event does not fire in Safari on my Mac or my iPad/iPhone.  I'm new to this, so it may be (and probably is) programmers' error, but here's my code:

```
<form class='send-form'>
    <input type="hidden" name="csv-val" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="img-val" value="">
    <button type='button' class='send-it' onclick='$(sendTheData(event))'>
        Manual Submit
    </button>
</form>

<script>
    function sendTheData(event){
        var sendButton = $(event.target);
        var theForm = sendButton.parents('form');
        var theFormClass = sendButton.parents('form').attr('class');
        console.log("Parent form is " + theFormClass);
        $.ajax({
            async: "true",
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'save.php',
            data: $(theForm).serialize()
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Note that the element with the class `send-form` is appended to the document by a different jQuery script and isn't on the page upon the initial load, so that might affect things; I'm not sure.

Comment: First of all, `onclick` should be `onclick="sendTheData(event);"`, modify it then try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did modify it, and unfortunately it didn't work.  I can tell in the that the `sendTheData` function is being called because it spits out a comment to the console, but the ajax event within that function isn't firing.

Comment: Check if the `url` is the correct one.
You're using `GET` method instead of `POST`.
`theForm` variable is already a jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it again, e.g. `theForm.serialize()`

Also, I don't get it why you're setting `theForm` variable the way you do, by finding `parent`, parent already has class `.send-form`, so you can simply change that variable to `var theForm = $('.send-form');`

Comment: The reason that I use find `parent` is that there's more than one of these forms with the class of `send-form`.  They are appended by a different jQuery function.  However, I did change the method from `GET` to `POST`, (and changed it from `GET` to `POST` in my PHP file), and it worked like a charm.  So thanks!  I don't know if you can submit that as a response instead of a comment so that I can mark it as correct, but if you can, it might be helpful to other users who come along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

- Correct the `onclick` attribute to `onclick="sendTheData(event);"`
- Check if the `url` is the correct one.
- Change the method from `GET` to `POST`.

Note regarding form's class: You could set `id` to the specific form then and bind the variable to that `id` instead of `class`. Try avoiding `parent()` and similar functions as they're using too much resources (you're making a loop through all the elements, then through the parents, and then finding the right one, instead of simply aiming for the right one directly).

Comment: Changing from `GET` to `POST` solved it!  Also, I implemented the `id` tip.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the fail callback, maybe you get some error...
You get an example for that on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/